# Retrieve the value selected in the Select box in to Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have couple of select box and a button like below

```
     <dx-select-box [dataSource]="criteria" (onValueChanged)="onValueChanged($event)" style="width: 350px"
        [stylingMode]="'outlined'">
     </dx-select-box>
  </div>
  <div class="dx-field">
     <dx-select-box [dataSource]="searchResults" (onValueChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)"
        [stylingMode]="'outlined'" style="width: 350px">
     </dx-select-box>
  </div>
  <div class="form-fields">
     <dx-button style="width:150px; height:50px;">Filter</dx-button>
  </div>
```

How can I push the selected value from both the selectbox in to the component when the Button is clicked. I am new to front end development, and not sure how to push data from html to component.

Comment: https://angular.io/start/forms

Comment: You can use simple binding to `value` like this:
`<dx-select-box [dataSource]="criteria" [(ngModel)]="valueFromBox1"></dx-select-box>` and `<dx-select-box [dataSource]="searchResults" [(ngModel)]="valueFromBox2"></dx-select-box>`. 
This way you will always have values in your component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in multiple ways. Here is a quick solution using template reference variables (Although I would always suggest to use template driven/reactive forms):

```
<dx-select-box [dataSource]="criteria" style="width: 350px"
    [stylingMode]="'outlined'" #first>
</dx-select-box>
</div>
<div class="dx-field">
    <dx-select-box [dataSource]="searchResults"
    [stylingMode]="'outlined'" style="width: 350px" #second>
</dx-select-box>
</div>
<div class="form-fields">
    <dx-button style="width:150px; height:50px;" (click)="submitValue(first.value, second.value)">Filter</dx-button>
</div>
```

And in component

```
submitValue(firstvalue, secondValue) {
    console.log(firstvalue);
    console.log(secondValue);
}
```

Simple template driven form example:
template:

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(form.value)">
  <div>
    <label>Firstname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" ngModel>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Lastname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" ngModel>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And in component:

```
submit(formValue) {
  console.log(formValue)
}
```

Make sure FormsModule is imported in app.module.ts

```
  import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
```

Comment: I have other fields too, how can it know first/second. Can you please show an example how can I use forms

Comment: I have added a simple example for template driven form. You need to change the input fields with the drop downs.